# Bug / Problem: Chat Function | Edit Feature | Readability | Browser "Google Chrome"

Tags: bug

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- If I want to edit a post in the chat then the text in the edit text box is white.
- By selecting the text I can read it, but it's hard to edit.
- I use Google Chrome.
- User https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex reported teh same problem (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45066478#45066478)

Comment: Does this also happen in chat rooms of other sites (which have other colour themes?)

Comment: @samcarter I do not use other chat rooms :(). You are my only online friends :)